# Kotlin: Android Studio - Print on Emulator not the same as print using Log.v(TAG

Tags: android, kotlin, repeat

```
fun division(){
    val numerator = 1000   
    var denominator = 4
    var index = 1
    val outputText = ("Result is ${numerator / denominator}")
    val indexText: TextView = findViewById(Rid.index_textview)
    val divisionText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.division_textView)

    repeat(3){                                  //repeats block three times
        Log.v(TAG, "${numerator / denominator}")//logs output to Logcat
        divisionText.text= outputText           //outputs the calculation text to emulator
        indexText.text = ("Index is $index")    //outputs the index value text to emulator
        Thread.sleep(1000)//milliseconds        //pauses 1 second between repeats
        denominator--                           //decrements denominator by 1
        index++                                 //increments index by 1
    }
}
```

When the code (incomplete here) is run in Android Studio on the emulator, I get one line of text for each indexText and divisionText, instead of three expected.  Additionally,the output for divisionText is 250 and the indexText is 3.  The Android Studio logcat outputs each division calculation correctly. When I run the code in Kotlin playground, the code gives me three lines each of indexText and divisionText.  However, the indexText value is output correctly, incrementing one more each repeat cycle, while the calculation of numerator / denominator only outputs the 'same' final calculation on each repeated line cycle.

Comment: i'm struggling to understand your question, do you expect there to be 3 values on your `divisionText` and you only have the final result ?

Comment: Hint: `Thread.sleep()` blocks the UI thread and prevents e.g. `TextView`s from redrawing themselves. Consider using e.g. coroutines to have a `delay` without blocking.

Comment: Ok..maybe it's because I am SO new.  Yes..is it possible to get the three different calculation values each time it repeats?

Comment: I was not aware that thread.sleep() blocked the UI from redrawing.  Thanks...a good step in the right direction.

Comment: Tyler V, I would love to give you a thumbs up but it won't let me!!

Comment: You can give "thumbs up" by accepting the answer (and upvoting if you have the rep)... That's how things work on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sleep statement on the UI thread, which blocks the UI and prevents any update to the displayed values until it is all done. Use a coroutine with a delay instead to have the numbers update properly at a 1 second interval, like this:

```kotlin
fun division(){
    val numerator = 1000
    var denominator = 4
    var index = 1
    val indexText: TextView = findViewById(Rid.index_textview)
    val divisionText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.division_textView)

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeat(3) {
            Log.v(TAG, "${numerator / denominator}")
            divisionText.text= "Result is ${numerator / denominator}"
            indexText.text = "Index is $index"
            delay(1000) //milliseconds
            denominator--
            index++
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to move your string creation to inside the loop so it updates properly each loop (before your `outputText` variable was constant, would not change when the variables got updated).

If you want to do this without using `lifecycleScope`, you can use `MainScope()` instead, like this

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.MainScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

//...

MainScope().launch {
    repeat(3) {
        // do stuff
        delay(1000)
    }
}
```

**Note**: You are also using integer division, so your result will be an integer, not a floating point number. If you want decimal output you need to convert the result to a double first, like this

```kotlin
val result = numerator / denominator.toDouble()
divisionText.text = "Result is $result"
```

or just change your numerator to a floating point type like this

```kotlin
val numerator = 1000.0
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your time in answering so thoroughly.  However, my head just went under...I tried your code and researched lifecycleScope.launch.  Apparently, there is a huge routine to go along with that not-so-little word.  As your code is written, I am sure you are assuming I know how to write the lifecycleScope.launch stuff and know what it means when a parameter needs to be passed to the 'delay' body.  Apparently, I have muuuuuuch to learn.  Alas, I shall continue my research on this lifecycleScope thing.  I'm giving your answer a check, because I don't know otherwise...sigh

Comment: If this is in an Activity you literally just write `lifecycleScope` - no other code is needed beyond what I posted (check [dependencies](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)). If it is not in an activity you can use `MainScope().launch` instead too. The parameter in `delay` is just the delay in milliseconds, just like the `sleep` call.

Comment: Thank you, but I entered your code and lifecycleScope is red...Do I need to import something.  I tried "import  androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0" and it didn't change anything.  And I get an error on "delay"...No value passed for parameter 'body'. You have led me down a good path. I will continue to trudge on.  Close only counts in the game of horse shoes...ugh  And I'm working in Android Studio...I'm going to try IntelliJ.  I found it is a little more intuitive sometimes.

Comment: Yes, look at the dependencies link I posted - you need to add `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0` to your **gradle file** for lifecycleScope (not as an import). For delay you just need to import it (and pass a number to it? I don't know why you would get that error unless you had imported a different `delay` method. I'll add the required imports to the answer too.)

Comment: Thank you greatly, Tyler!  Still trudging...

Comment: Try the version I added using `MainScope()`, then you don't have to add anything to your gradle file. It only needs the three imports I added.

Comment: Ok, Tyler... Your code was right on!!!  I'm posting my naivety so that it may help others.  What I didn't do right, and why the MainScope didn't work for me originally was because I didn't know you had to select the word MainScope as you were typing!  It didn't recognize the, the, whatever MainScope is, as being a reserved word, or whatever you call it.  AND...you were correct, I needed to move the division problem into the repeat so that it would update to get a new "result."  Also, the import of kotlinx.coroutines.* came in no problem without errors.  Will add comment+ to show final code.

Comment: One thing I would like to point out is that the 'thread, sleep' line was what was suggested in the Android Developer Training Course.  Very frustrating for a person trying to learn something if the instructions are incorrect.  I sent them a screenshot and reported the problem.  They said all quotients should appear, one after another, using that code.  Ugh...wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked, Thanks to Tyler!

```
package com.example.debugging2

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    fun division(args: Array>String>) {
        val numerator = 1000.0
        var denominator = 4.0
        var index = 1
        val indexText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.index_textview)
        val divisionText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.division_textview)
        
        MainScope().launch {
            repeat(4)
                val result = numerator / denominator
                Log.v(TAG, "$result")
                divisionText.text = ("Division result is $result")
                indexText.text = ("Index is $index\n") //new line
                denominator--
                index++
                delay(1000)
        }
    }
}

    fun logging() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: a serious error like an app crash")
        Log.w(TAG, "Warn: warns about the potential for serious errors")
        Log.i(TAG, "Info: reporting technical information, such as an operation        
                    succeeding"
        Log.d(TAG, "Debug: reporting technical information useful for debugging.")
        Log.v(TAG, "Verbose: more verbose than DEBUG logs")
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        logging()
        division(arrayOf())
    }
}
```